# React native mapping and displaying array of objects

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

the views with card styles not showing unless taken out of the array reslist mapping
anything wrong with my code ?
reslit is an array that reads data from firestore database
bellow is the console log of the array
been stuck on this not showing up for 3 days now
[enter image description here][1]

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
var reslist = [];

  db
  .collection('Rests')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      reslist.push({
        name:doc.data().name,
        description:doc.data().description,
        title:doc.data().title,
        rating:doc.data().rating,
        open:doc.data().open,
        close:doc.data().close,
        location:doc.data().location,
       // menu:doc.data().menu,
    })
    console.log(reslist)
    //console.log(doc.data().menu)
    });
  });
return(
{
             reslist.map( Res => 
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate("Details",Res.id)}}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={styles.cardImgWrapper}>
              <Image
                source={require('./../../assets/food-banner1.jpg')}
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={styles.cardImg}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardInfo}>
              <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{Res.title}</Text>
              <StarRating ratings={Res.rating} reviews={350} />
              <Text style={styles.cardDetails}>
                {Res.description}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
         )
              }
)
```

console log of array :

> Array [
>
> > Object {
> > "close": "23",
> > "description": "royal restaurant description ...",
> > "location": t {
> > "U": 33.853366,
> > "k": 10.102713,
> > },
> > "name": "Royal",
> > "open": 10,
> > "rating": 4,
> > "title": "Restaurant",
> > },
> > Object {
> > "close": 23,
> > "description": ""farwest description twila w ba3d we have to add ... to not show only in setails screen with multiple menus"",
> > "location": t {
> > "U": 33.850653,
> > "k": 10.106268,
> > },
> > "name": "Farwest",
> > "open": 7,
> > "rating": 5,
> > "title": "coffee",
> > },
> > ]

here is the data structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTh5m.png

Comment: can you help us paste what every element of `reslist.map( Res => console.log(Res))` has ?

Comment: here it is https://ibb.co/HX45r0R

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function Example() {

 const [reslist, setReslist] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   getFireBaseData();
 });

 const getFireBaseData = () => {

   const db = firebase.firestore();
   var reslistData = [];

   db
   .collection('Rests')
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      reslistData.push({
        name:doc.data().name,
        description:doc.data().description,
        title:doc.data().title,
        rating:doc.data().rating,
        open:doc.data().open,
        close:doc.data().close,
        location:doc.data().location,
       // menu:doc.data().menu,
     })
    });
  });
  
  setReslist(reslistData); // this will reflect on view

 }

 return( { 
       reslist.map( Res => ...)
     })
}
```